# Install windows in VM

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine

I am upgrading my C drive (500GB SSD -> 1TB SSD). I wanted first to make a clean install on the new drive via VM (windows 10 in dual boot with Ubuntu), transfer everything I need, before switching the drives physically.

Will that work according to you ?

Am I missing any detail that could make this fail when I switch ?

Which VM client would you advise ? (it's been a while since I last played with any)

Answer (score 1):

Installing via a VM can work, but seems like an extraneous step.  And yes, there can be issues.

You might run into issues with EFI if its used. or with the disk controller not being recognized.  The VM will not have any drivers for the real hardware.

In my opinion, doing this through a VM just adds more work, possible issues, and I dont see any benefit.

If you have a spare SATA port on your motherboard, I would just connect the drive to it and install from there.  That is a much easier method.  Tgis can allow you to boot and access all drives.  You can then do whatever you want with the original drive.  Such as leave it in and reuse it, or remove it.